# How do I put two adverbs together in a sentence?

Tags: adverbs

How do I put two adverbs in a sentence like this one:

> All independent variables **simultaneously, significantly** affect dependent variables

Comment: Use "and" between the adverbs.

Comment: Quickly and easily?

Comment: Of course if you don’t like the way it sounds you could change to adjectives- *All independent variables have a simultaneous and significant effect on dependent variables*

Answer (score 2):

> All independent variables simultaneously, significantly affect dependent variables.

1. All independent variables simultaneously and significantly affect dependent variables.
2. All independent variables affect dependent variables [both] simultaneously and significantly.

For stylistic reasons and for readability I prefer version 2.

Note that there is some ambiguity. Do **all** independent variables affect **all** dependent variables? However that is a separate issue and has nothing to do with the placement of adverbs.

Comment: Great explanation @chasly!

Comment: It is the *affecting* which is simultaneous and significant.  So put the adverbs as close as possible to "affect".

Comment: But "All independent variables affect dependent variables, i.e.X price and Production cost, both simultaneously and significantly" is rather clumsy, no?

Comment: "Get it quickly delivered home." Is it correct?